# Excel freezes when executing code, but code works fine when stepped through via F8?

Tags: excel, vba, freeze

Im pretty much desperate right now. I have a lengthy section of code that is executed by pressing a button on a worksheet. The code itself initiates several other subs, functions and userforms. When I press that button, it executes some part of the code until the excel file freezes. When I step through the code via F8 however, it works just fine! How can that be?!

I would love to show you the code, but it is way too long and as I said involves various links to other subs etc.
Hence my question: Can anyone think of general problems that might result in this issue?!

Thanks alot!

Comment: Please create a small code that replicates the issue, a [mcve].  As is we can only guess.

Comment: We can't debug code we can't see, and this site isn't designed for *Here's a vague problem description with no code. Please speculate on what might be wrong* type posts. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), particularly the section with the numbered list of items. The process of distilling it down to a [mcve] will most likely help you determine the problem area of the code yourself, and may even allow you to find a solution to the problem.

Comment: At a guess, you are using `.Select`/`.Activate` and/or not qualifying ranges with their worksheets, and/or leaving `Calculation` on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your answers. I have found the problem to the issue. It turned out that I had a never ending Loop in the code and did not find it using F8 because I changed some of the code in the process. Stupid mistake after a long day of coding. Sorry about that!